# SAP UI5 - Change colour of Input added dynamically from js Controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm new on Fiori and I need help to set colour at inputs that I added dynamically from my controller.
That's my code:

```
var ColumnHeader = new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Label({
              text: i.toString(),
            }),
            hAlign: "Center",
          });

// that's my input
var cell = new sap.m.Input({
            value: i.toString() + "%",
          });
// I think here I need to add code to change colour

          oColumnListItem.addCell(cell);
          oTable.addColumn(ColumnHeader);
```

Can someone help me?
Best Reguards

Comment: Could you specify the "colour of input" a bit more? Do you mean the background of the input field (e.g. instead of white)? The font colour? Border colour? And what purpose does changing the colour have? Is it semantic (e.g. red for an invalid user input)? Or just theming the input field style?

Comment: And what is the result of your research so far?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I mean background colour. It's an app that show yellow input for days CEDI and orange input for days POS. Above it's the code for the first loop so need to put yello colour. @BoghyonHoffmann

Comment: Apart from applying the colour depending on the value (`CEDI`, `POS`), do those colours have any semantic meaning? E.g. yellow for "highlighting", orange as a "warning", and possibly red für "critical", etc? Or are those colours just for the sake of styling without any semantic meaning behind?

Comment: With standard you can put a specific ValueState on your sap.m.Input
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputValueState

With your code will be on the property of cell ( valueState : "xxx" }
But if the required valuestate dont fit your color requirement then you can create a css class like .customColor and then you can use cell.addStyleClass("customColor") to add the class to your sap.m.Input